# Соединение с бд в готовом проекте jar

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, javafx, jar

Есть проект, работающий с бд. Создаю jar файл этого проекта, однако не происходит взаимодействие с бд, нужно сделать бэкап бд и засунуть в папку проекта, как это делается вообще? Приложение Java FX, бд MySQL

Comment: слишком пространный вопрос и он не один.. непонятно что значит не происходит взаимодействие ? чтобы все работало, должны быть правильные настройки подключения к бд, jar проекта должен знать где лежит драйвер к бд, то есть либо путь указывается в classpath при запуске приложения, либо прописывается в манифесте прописывается относительный путь к драйверу (относительно расположения самого проекта), есть еще извратный вариант добавить jar драйвера к бд в сам проект, ну и в завершение правильный путь куда делается бекап

Comment: @keekkenen, вопрос в том, как сгенерировать готовое приложение, имеющие бд, так чтобы это приложение работало соответственно без среды разработки и взаимодействовало с бд

Comment: если есть приложение, которое в IDE работает, значит осталось упаковать его в jar и при запуске указать путь к драйверу базы